# Google - Verify your identity on new account

Tags: email, vpn, login, gmail, verification

I have created a new Google account using an existing email (that has a custom domain). Upon my first login, I was greeted with the following page for supposed unusual activity:

[image: Verify your identity].

I have tried over 10 mobile numbers from over 4 countries, and they all returned some error, most common of which is: 'This phone number cannot be used for verification'.

I have also tried using a VPN, and temporary phone numbers to no avail.

How can I get past this verification step?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that it wants a French mobile number. The more you are trying to fool it, the more red flags you are raising.

A VPN is unlikely to work. And you need to be in France for best results.

If this combination is not working for you, just create a new email address.

---

I dont think that you can get past this step.  A Google account has an implied/default country associated with, which can be changed once a year.
Your domain has a country associated with it as well. Your mobile as a country associated with it based on location (not GPS) and ISP connected to.  And your phone number is implying yet another country. For whatever reason, it is confused with the your domain, your account and your phone.

Without knowing extensive details, I would suggest that you use a different email address.

Comment: I chose France as I have a French number. I also have a Lebanese number which also didn't work.